# String concatenation in JavaScript with quote literals

Tags: javascript, string-concatenation

I am having issues specifying quote literals in JavaScript. How do I create a string that will be equivalent to the following?

```
<li><a onclick="goSomePlace('SomeName')">SomeName</a></li>
```

Comment: Whenever you use the same quotation marks in a string that you use to  delimit the literal, you have to escape them with ``\``.

Comment: "concatenation" is actually when you join two strings together, unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you: (escaped single quotes in function param)

```
var string = '<li><a onclick="goSomePlace(\'SomeName\')">SomeName</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 5):

You must use escapes:

`var str = "<li><a onclick=\"goSomePlace('SomeName')\">SomeName</a></li>";`

or

`var str = '<li><a onclick="goSomePlace(\'SomeName\')">SomeName</a></li>";`

strings in javascript can be surrounded either by `"` or `'`.  When using the same character as the character used to surround the string, you must escape it with `\`

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = "<li><a onclick=\"goSomePlace('SomeName')\">SomeName</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape with "\",

```
var s = "<li><a onclick="goSomePlace(\'SomeName\')">SomeName</a></li>';
var s = "<li><a onclick='goSomePlace(\"SomeName\")'>SomeName</a></li>";
var s = '<li><a onclick=\'goSomePlace("SomeName")\'>SomeName</a></li>';
```